# PSR-4 Autoloading Class

Tags: php, composer-php, autoloader, psr-4

I am adding some custom classes to a project. I am struggling to get psr-4 autoloading to work.

I am placing my custom classes in a folder at [project root]/lib
Here is the autoload bit from my composer.json:

```
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/src",
        "Lib\\": "lib"
    }
},
```

I have a file P_Database.php in the lib folder with the following declarations:

```
 <?PHP
namespace Lib;

class P_Database
{
     //
```

I call the class in a file with:

```
 use Lib\P_Database;
 require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
 $db = new P_Database();
```

I get a 500 error:

```
 PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Lib\\P_Database' not found....
```

I have run composer dump-autoload.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: does it work if you move the require statement above the use statement?

Comment: @fire no. Tried it; same result.

Comment: have you run composer dump-autoload?

Comment: Does the `App` namespace work properly ? Try adding a `/` at the end of your paths.

Comment: @KubaBirecki Yes, App namespace works; tried adding training /, same result

Comment: con you show us your tree view of the folder that contain `composer.json`?

Comment: All: thanks for your time. I have no idea why, but this morning, with no changes to my code, this is working correctly.